# SQL Programming question

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @Item as char(32)
declare @result varchar(max)
SET @Item = 'FL1823'

with Bom
 (
 StartItem, MasterItem, Position, SubItem, SubItemDescription, EffectDate, ExpiryDate, NetQuantity, UnitOfMeasure, BomLevel, Dots, Sort) as
(
select t_mitm as StartItem, t_mitm, t_pono, t_sitm, t_dsca, t_indt, t_exdt, t_qana, t_cuni, 0 as BomLevel, CONVERT(varchar(255),'.'), CONVERT(varchar(255),RTrim(t_mitm) + ' ' +RTrim(t_sitm))

from ttibom010101 INNER JOIN ttiitm001101 on t_sitm = t_item where t_mitm =@Item

UNION ALL

SELECT     StartItem, t_mitm, t_pono, t_sitm, t_dsca, t_indt, t_exdt, NetQuantity * t_qana, t_cuni,BomLevel + 1, CONVERT(varchar(255),'.' + Dots), CONVERT(varchar(255),RTrim(Sort)+ ' ' + RTrim(t_sitm))
FROM         (ttibom010101 INNER JOIN ttiitm001101 on t_sitm = t_item) INNER JOIN
                     Bom ON t_mitm = SubItem where t_exdt= '1753-01-01'
)
Select * from Bom order by Sort
```

I keep getting an error saying incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: WITH was added in SQL2005.  What version of the database engine are you using?  If you're not sure:  Select @@Version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put a semi colon before the 'with' - it has to be the first element in a statement

Comment: @gabrielVA Also, you are missing the word `AS`. It should be like this: `SET @ITEM = 'FL1823';  WITH Bom AS (`

Comment: @Lamak: there is an `AS` at the end of the line.